# Redirect to selected site with variable which i got

Tags: html, forms, submit

```
<form action="/subsite/" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Your Nick">
  <input class="button" type="submit" />
</form>
```

I want to redirect I mean it should looks like
*www/subsite/text*
What should I use ? POST ?

Comment: If you are trying to redirect to '/subsite/text' you cannot do this with poor html. You must use some javascript here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `method="get"` means that the parameters (and values) will be sent in the query string (the stuff after the question mark in the URL). eg.
`/subsite?input_field_name=input_field_value`

In your case, the input field doesn't have a name, which will cause problems. You probably want something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="Your Nick">
```

So if you submit this form:

```
<form action="/subsite" method="get">
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="Your Nick">
</form>
```

Then after submitting, the browser will go to:
/subsite?nickname=value_of_nickname_variable

If you use a `method="post"`, then the form data (variables) will be sent along in the request body, not the query string. There are other differences between get/post, but that's one of them :)

If you just want to do a simple redirect when clicking the button, you could use javascript instead, eg.: `window.location.href='/my_url_path_here'`

Comment: <form action="">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Nick" type="text"><input onclick="window.location.href = '/player/' + this.value;" class="button" type="submit" />
</form>   i have no idea :C

Comment: I put some sample html & javascript here: http://jsbin.com/noxoxodicu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I just did it using php :) But thanks you that was very helpful!